# Is an EASA flight school required to give me my training records if I leave?

Tags: flight-training, easa-regulations

I am having troubles with my flight school in Austria/Europe. So I want to change school but the school won't give me my training records so I can't finish my training somewhere else.

Is there any EASA regulation that states they have to return my records?

Comment: Have you asked them to transfer the records straight to another school? I had a similar issue here in Australia where I was not allowed the records about me but they were happy to send them to another school.